# Why i can not use partial classes on asp.net website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have to work with a website project and need to use partial classes. But there is a problem with using.

**TestPartial.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TestPartial.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestPartial" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>

   </div>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**TestPartial.aspx.cs**

```
using System;

public partial class TestPartial : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public int price = 200;

    partial void Salary();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Salary();

       int newPrice = price;
    }
}
```

**TestPartial2.aspx.cs**

```
using System;

public partial class TestPartial : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    partial void Salary()
    {
        price = 400;
    }
}
```

**Error:**

Error   1   The name 'Salary' does not exist in the current context

Comment: It will help http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/071509-1.aspx

Comment: I just tried it myself when creating a new WebForm project and it should work. Are both partial class files in the same assembly?

Comment: Are you sure everything is in the same namespace?

Comment: @Jensen When you tried this code with a web application, it is working good. But as i said above, it must be website. Please right click on your solution and add a new website, tried the same code in this project. You will see the problem.

Comment: @Tobberoth They are in the same namespace.

Comment: Ah, a __web-site__. That makes it harder to get both in the same compile. Are you sure you need partial? I would look for another solution.

Comment: Maybe i can do it in a different way but i want to know if i can create partial classes, why can not use them? Or what is the way of using?

Comment: Your problem is the Web-site and how it compiles stuff. That clashes with partial.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the `Test()` method on the calling side. Making it `public` may be possible but does not seem a very good idea.

```
public partial class TestPartial : System.Web.UI.Page
{    
    partial void Test(); // add this line

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Test();
    }
}


public partial class TestPartial : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    partial void Test()  
    {
         // executed from Page_Load
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I don't have an aspx project open. If there are problems, post the error messages.

Comment: please see edits on my question. Can you try it? Your answer prevents error, builds but i think it is not working

Comment: Check your edits, Test() isn't there anymore and I expect an error with `price` now.

Comment: Use completely above class contents, there is no error with me, im waiting newPrice value is 400 but it is 200. This means TestPartial2 is not compiling, isnt it? Already ahen i put a breakpoint on Salary method, it is not working